# Installing an openssh-LPK patch on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, ssh-keys, openssh, apt

I am attempting to install an openssh-lpk( http://code.google.com/p/openssh-lpk/ ) patch on ubuntu(either 10.04 or 10.10) to enable authentication through ssh keys stored in an ldap directory.  It seems like there are two options to do this.

Either apply the patch to openssh manually

or

Install a patched openssh from an ubuntu ppa here https://launchpad.net/~sfire/+archive/ssh-lpk.
When attempting to install from the ppa I can successfully add the repository but once I run apt-get update and try to install with

```
apt-get install openssh
```

I get an error saying no such package exists.

Any help on installing an lpk patched openssh would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you look in http://ppa.launchpad.net/sfire/ssh-lpk/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssh/ there is no package `openssh`. You want `openssh-client` and/or `openssh-server`.

```
# apt-get install openssh-client
```

Do the same for `openssh-server` if you want that.

Comment: Ah, Thanks.  However when I install openssh-client or server It always install the more recent version of openssh without the lpk patch 5.3p1-ubuntu7. How can I force apt to install the 5.3p1-3ubuntu3lpk0.

Comment: Figured this out `apt-get install openssh-server=1:5.3p1-3ubuntu3lpk0`